# Adding older history from svn project with git svn

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I downloaded an svn repository with

```
git svn clone -s svn+ssh://svn.dummy.com -r666666:HEAD
```

Now I'd like to add older history to the project. Can I do this later on or do I have to download the whole project again?

What I basically want to achieve is checking out a huge package with its history. `git svn` always crashes at some point. `SubGit` doesn't work at all (for me) with svn+ssh. Alternatives are welcome.

Comment: `git svn` will usually crash at some point, but it can simply be resumed by doing `git svn fetch` as many times as is needed until you have the entire history.

Comment: KDE's svn2git tool is able to handle very large subversion repositories.  http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/switching-svn-repository-svn2git

Comment: @onionjake `git svn fetch` would resume sometimes, but stops working at some point. I never managed to get the whole history of this huge repository without running into a perl error.

Comment: @onionjake `svn2git` would change the svn repository into a git repository, but I cannot commit to the svn repository later on. For the same reason SubGit does not work for me.

Comment: What version of git are you using?

Comment: @onionjake git version 2.4.0.rc2.18.g1eb0545

Answer (score 5):

Two advices: import/convert the entire Subversion repository from the beginning and use [SubGit](http://www.subgit.com) for conversion.

It is possible to add older history later (I did it two years ago) but it is not fun at all. Some requirements need to be met in order to be possible and the process is not straight forward. `git` itself does not help you very much as this is a very unusual operation. You can find the entire workflow, step by step, in [this article](http://axiac.ro/blog/2014/11/merging-git-repositories/).

More, it will confuse your workmates because the commit identifiers change in the process and they will end up with duplicate commits (commits with the same message and file changes but with different hashes).

[SubGit](http://www.subgit.com) does a better conversion than `git svn`. The timeline it generates looks more like the original Subversion timeline.

Comment: Importing the whole subversion history with `git svn` would take several days. I tried, but it always crashes at some point. That's why I wanted to gradually add older history to it. Does SubGit replace git svn? If so, I'll give it a try.

Comment: SubGit is an independent software that can act as a bi-directional `svn`-`git` gateway (pushing to `svn` as many `git` features as `svn` supports or can be translated somehow) but it can also be used for a [one-time import from Subversion into Git](http://www.subgit.com/remote-book.html#7). My repository had about only about 300 commits (PHP files, several images, no big binary files) and the conversion completed in several minutes. I don't know how it performs on large repositories. Give it a try, maybe it can help you.

Comment: If you convert the `svn` repository to `git` in slices you can join them easily using `git remote` (to connect the repos) and `git rebase` (to do the actual join). You will lose the commit dates in the process (author dates are not affected). The lengthy article I linked in the answer is about how to (backup them before the `rebase` and) restore them (afterwards).

Comment: After checking out SubGit for a few hours, I'm convinced that it is not the tool I'm looking for. It would not accept my key for authentication and wants to store my password undecrypted on the filesystem. Moreover, checking out a package is very cumbersome, since `subgit import` would always fail, reporting "error: Username must be specified in configuration file for 'svn+ssh' connection", although the user name was specified.

Comment: Try to use the format `svn+ssh://username@host/path-to-repository` for the `--svn-url` argument. The password is probably stored (encrypted or not) inside the `.svn` subdirectory of your home directory (where `svn` itself keeps the passwords, encrypted or not, and its configuration files). You can easily identify and remove it afterwards, if it's there.

Comment: This fixes my issue with the username. I still don't like to store my password unencrypted on the filesystem. However, the cloning process is very fast, 20 minutes compared to more than 20 hours. I now have a git project, but I still don't know how to push/dcommit to the svn project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80673/discussion-between-axiac-and-pfnuesel).